# XSLT - Value-Of

Tags: xslt

the same way you can do the following...

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd[artist='Bob Dylan']">
```

Can you do the same filtering with the Value-Of statement?

```
<xsl:value-of select="value[name='Name']" />
```

Thanks,
james.

Edit:

Sorry for the confusion.

I had some XML:

```
<DynamicData>
    <item>
      <name>Name</name>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:int">0</value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <name>Value</name>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:long">9</value>
    </item>
</DynamicData>
```

I wanted to use a filter on my value-of select, much in the same way as is possible when doing a for-each. I've only just started looking at XSLT, so wasnt sure of its abilities. In the end i used the following XSLT:

```
<set>   
    <xsl:attribute name="name"> 
       <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="item[name='Name']/value=0">Low</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="item[name='Name']/value=1">Medium</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="item[name='Name']/value=2">High</xsl:when>  
       </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
    ...
```

The problem I was having was i was putting the filter after the value element in the test, like so. `<xsl:when test="item/value[name='Name']=2">High</xsl:when>` Obviously the 'name' element isnt an element of 'value' but an element of 'item' hence why this didnt work.

Thanks for your help everyone, i got there in the end :)

Comment: What is your desired result, could you provide some sample input/output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, select takes an XPATH expression as it's argument

[XSL:value-of](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_value-of.asp)

Whilst the specification states you can, it could depend on the implementation your XML/XSL engine.

Comment: It is indeed possible, the problem i was having was i was doing the filtering 'too far' into the elements so to speak. I was doing "item/value[name='Name']" instead of "item[name='Name']/value". The 'name element was an element of 'item' and not 'value'

Answer (score 2):

**Remember that in XSLT 1.0** `<xsl:value-of select="someNodeSet"/>` outputs only the string value of the *first* node in `someNodeSet`

**On the other side**:

```
<xsl:for-each select="someNodeSet">
 <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

outputs the string value of *every* node in `someNodeSet`.

Comment: You're speaking of XSLT 1.0. In 2.0, xsl:value-of outputs all the values, space separated, (and allows you to choose a different separator).

Comment: @Michael Kay: Edited the answer to explicitly say: "in XSLT 1.0"

Comment: In XSLT 1.0 `xsl:copy-of` and `text()` test  node could effectively replace the `xsl:for-each` as used by OP.

Comment: @empo: Of course. But the question he is asking is to compare `<xsl:for-each>` and `<xsl:value-of>`

Comment: Are we sure the OP is asking to compare, they've only asked about the filtering aspect

Comment: Yeah i was interested in the aspect of filtering, can value-of filter like for-each can.

Comment: @Cadab et all: You are asking: Can X be used "*like*" Y  .  This is quite clearly asking for a comparison. And my answer says: yes, but not exactly in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: The added value of my question was just providing a way to emulate the behavior the OP asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Do note that in XSLT 1.0 you can workaround this with `xsl:copy-of` and `text()` test node.

---

Example, given this input:

```
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <artist>Pink Floyd</artist>
        <title>ummagumma</title>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <artist>Pink Floyd</artist>
        <title>Atom Earth Mother</title>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

You can use `xsl:copy-of` as follows:

```
 <xsl:copy-of select="catalog/cd[artist='Pink Floyd']/title/text()"/>
```

will return the value of all the matching nodes exactly as in:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd[artist='Pink Floyd']/title">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:for-each>
```