# Retrieving multiple values from a block in XML through XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report xmlns:fpml="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation" xmlns="http://www.eurexchange.com/EurexIRSFullInventoryReport" name="CB202 Full Inventory Report">
 <reportNameGrp>
  <CM>
   <acctTypGrp name="A4">
    <ProductType name="Swap">
     <currTypCod value="EUR">
     </currTypCod>
     <currTypCod value="GBP">
     </currTypCod>
    </ProductType>
   </acctTypGrp>
   <acctTypGrp name="A8">
    <ProductType name="Swap">
     <currTypCod value="CHF">
     </currTypCod>
     <currTypCod value="EUR">
     </currTypCod>
     <currTypCod value="GBP">
     </currTypCod>
    </ProductType>
   </acctTypGrp>
  </CM>
 </reportNameGrp>
</Report>
```

for which I used this XSLT transformation (based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/27458587/2564301):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:fpml="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:eur="http://www.eurexchange.com/EurexIRSFullInventoryReport">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/eur:Report">
        <Eurexflows>
            <xsl:apply-templates
                select="eur:reportNameGrp/eur:CM/eur:acctTypGrp/eur:ProductType" />
        </Eurexflows>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="eur:ProductType">
        <EurexMessageObject>
            <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="../@name" />
            </name>
            <ProductType>
                <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
            </ProductType>
            <value>
            <xsl:value-of select="eur:currTypCod/@value" />
            </value>
        </EurexMessageObject>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now I want my output XML to be like this:

```
<Eurexflows xmlns:eur="http://www.eurexchange.com/EurexIRSFullInventoryReport"
    xmlns:fpml="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation">

    <EurexMessageObject>
<name>A4</name>
<ProductType>Swap</ProductType>
<value>EUR,GBP</value>
</EurexMessageObject>
    <EurexMessageObject>
        <name>A8</name>
        <ProductType>Swap</ProductType>
        <value>CHF,EUR,GBP</value>
    </EurexMessageObject>
</Eurexflows>
```

What changes do I need in my XSLT with respect to the `value` tag?

Answer (score 2):

`value-of` does not work with multiple matching elements:

> ... in XSLT 1.0 `<xsl:value-of select="someNodeSet"/>` outputs only the string value of the *first* node in `someNodeSet` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6913772/2564301)

Use `<xsl:for-each>` instead of the single `value-of`:

```
<value>
   <xsl:for-each select="eur:currTypCod/@value">
     <xsl:if test="position()&gt;1">,</xsl:if>
     <xsl:value-of select="." />
   </xsl:for-each>
</value>
```